# React hooks context - how to update context with onclick event handler ? Getting Invalid hook call err when I try

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying to update a context with a callback. When I execute the callback its fine, but when I try to update the property inside of it im getting the err Error: Invalid hook call. Im not very familiar with context and researched and cant figure it out. Any help would be great. Thank you.

```
const initialState = {
  language:"en",
  showSomething:false,
  setShowSomething:setShowSomething
}


const StateContext = createContext(initialState)

export const useGlContext = () => {
  const glContext = useContext(StateContext)
  return glContext
}

function setShowSomething(el) {
  const context = useGlContext()
  context.showSomething=el
}

function App() {
  const context = useContext(StateContext)
  const { language, showSomething, setShowSomething } = context
  return (
    <Child 
    language={language}
    showSomething={showSomething}
    setShowSomething={setShowSomething}
    />
  )
const Child = ({language, showSomething, setShowSomething }) => {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => setShowSomething(true)}></button>
    )
}
}
```

Edit:

I am wrapping the root component inside Provider:

```
    <StateContext.Provider value={initialState}>
       <App />
    </StateContext.Provider>
```

Comment: Where is the Context.Provider?

Comment: This code would throw errors for multiple reasons, please make sure you share the correct implementation.

1. ```initialState``` is using ```setShowSomething``` which declared later
2. There is no `useContext`

Comment: I corrected it (its of course not my actual code). i use useContext so not sure what you mean

Comment: @BadalSaibo do I need to wrap something inside the Provider when I use hooks? and if that would it be where I have the onClick event?

Comment: make a context class of desired name and extend it with component make state of desired context values and in return method pass the context provider component with change handler and state values as props.
in your desired component from where u want to update the context value call that change handler like `yourAppContext.changehandler(someValue)` It works i do it this way its pretty straight forward and easy

Comment: @juliascoding Is your problem solved?

Answer (score -1):

You should take into account that event argument is passed in onClick.
Try:

```
onClick={event => setShowSomething(event,true)}
```

Consider using arrow functions:

```
const setShowSomething = (event, el) => {
  event.preventDefault(); <- must add for no infinite rerender
  const context = useGlContext()
  context.showSomething=el
}
```

Comment: no, there is no event passed. it is a button, not input.